# Texture artifact when converting cartesian to spherical coordinates

Tags: c++, math, textures

I am trying to write functions allowing me to manipulate textures and I encoutered a problem that I think might be due to double precision , but I'm not sure.
First , I'm loading an HDR image so I can compute an irradiance map of it. I need to convert pixels coordinates to UV , UV to spherical coordinates , then cartesian back and forth .

When I check how the conversion  UV -> spherical -> UV , it seems to be valid :

[image]

On the other hand , converting UV -> spherical -> cartesian -> spherical -> UV gives me this :

[image]

There are two seams : one at x = 0.5 , and one less visible at x = 0 .

In addition , the weird thing is that this seam has a uniform RGB value , no matter the fact pixels are using bilinear interpolation .
Here is the code I'm using in the class that computes the interpolation :

```
#ifndef OFFLINECUBEMAPPROCESSING_H
#define OFFLINECUBEMAPPROCESSING_H
#include "Texture.h"
#include "../kernels/CubemapProcessing.cuh"
#include <sstream>


constexpr long double epsilon = 1e-10; 
constexpr glm::dvec3 RED = glm::dvec3(1. , 0 , 0); 
constexpr glm::dvec3 YELLOW = glm::dvec3(0 , 1 , 1); 
constexpr glm::dvec3 GREEN = glm::dvec3(0 , 1 ,0);
constexpr glm::dvec3 BLUE = glm::dvec3(0 , 0 , 1);
constexpr glm::dvec3 BLACK = glm::dvec3(0); 

template <class T> 
class EnvmapProcessing{
public:

/**
 * @brief Construct a texture from an envmap double HDR with 3 channels 
 * 
 * @param _data 
 * @param _width 
 * @param _height 
 */
EnvmapProcessing(const T *_data , const unsigned _width , const unsigned _height , 
    const unsigned int num_channels = 3){
    width = _width ; 
    height = _height ;
    channels = num_channels ; 
    for(unsigned i = 0 ; i < width * height * num_channels ; i+=num_channels){
        data.push_back(glm::vec3(_data[i] , _data[i+1] , _data[i+2])); 
    } 
 }
virtual ~EnvmapProcessing(){}

const std::vector<glm::vec3>& getData(){return data;}

/**
 * @brief Computes the radiance map according to the roughness values
 * 
 * @param roughness 
 * @return TextureData 
 */
TextureData computeSpecularIrradiance(double roughness);

/* Implementation of templated methods*/
public:

/**
 * @brief Get the normalized UV in [0 , 1] range , from [0 ,width/height] coordinates.
 * @tparam D Type of coordinates .
 * @param x Width coordinates in the range [0 , width[.
 * @param y Height coordinates in the range [0 , height[.
 * @return const glm::dvec2 UVs in the range [0 , 1].
 */
template<class D>
inline const glm::dvec2 getUvFromPixelCoords(const D x , const D y) const {
    return glm::dvec2(static_cast<long double>(x) / static_cast<long double>(width - 1) , static_cast<long double>(y) / static_cast<long double>(height - 1)) ; 
} 

/**
 * @brief Get the Pixel Coords From Uv object
 * 
 * @tparam D 
 * @param u 
 * @param v 
 * @return const glm::dvec2 
 */
template<class D>
inline const glm::dvec2 getPixelCoordsFromUv(const D u , const D v) const {
        return glm::dvec2(u * (static_cast<double>(width) - 1) , v * (static_cast<double>(height) - 1)); 
}


/**
 * @brief This method wrap around if the texture coordinates provided land beyond the texture dimensions, repeating the texture values on both axes. 
 * 
 * @tparam D Data type of the coordinates.
 * @param u Horizontal UV coordinates.
 * @param v Vertical UV coordinates.
 * @return const glm::dvec2 Normalized coordinates in the [0 , 1] range.
 */
template<class D>
inline const glm::dvec2 wrapAroundTexCoords(const D u , const D v) const {
    D u_integer = 0 , v_integer = 0 ; 
    D u_double_p = 0. , v_double_p = 0. ; 
    u_integer = std::floor(u); 
    v_integer = std::floor(v); 
    if(u > 1. || u < 0.)
        u_double_p = u - u_integer ; 
    else
        u_double_p = u ; 
    if (v > 1. || v < 0.)
        v_double_p = v - v_integer ;  
    else
        v_double_p = v ;
    return glm::dvec2(u_double_p , v_double_p); 
}       

/**
 * @brief Normalizes a set of pixel coordinates into texture bounds. 
 *       
 * @param x Horizontal coordinates. 
 * @param y Vertical coordinates.
 * @return const glm::dvec2 Normalized coordinates 
 */
inline const glm::dvec2 wrapAroundPixelCoords(const int x , const int y) const {
    unsigned int x_coord = 0 , y_coord = 0 ;
    int _width = static_cast<int>(width); 
    int _height = static_cast<int>(height);  
    if(x >= _width)
        x_coord = x % _width ; 
    else if(x < 0)
        x_coord = _width + (x % _width) ; 
    else
        x_coord = x ; 
    if(y >= _height)
        y_coord = y % _height ; 
    else if(y < 0)
        y_coord = _height + (y % _height); 
    else
        y_coord = y ;
    return glm::dvec2(x_coord , y_coord) ; 
}

/**
* @brief Computes an interpolation between 4 pixels. 
* 
* @param top_left 
* @param top_right 
* @param bottom_left 
* @param bottom_right 
* @param point 
* @return * const T 
*/
const glm::dvec3 bilinearInterpolate(const glm::dvec2 top_left , const glm::dvec2 top_right , const glm::dvec2 bottom_left , const glm::dvec2 bottom_right , const glm::dvec2 point) const {
    const double u = (point.x - top_left.x) / (top_right.x - top_left.x); 
    const double v = (point.y - top_left.y) / (bottom_left.y - top_left.y);
    const glm::dvec3 top_interp = (1 - u) * discreteSample(top_left.x , top_left.y) + u * discreteSample(top_right.x , top_right.y);
    const glm::dvec3 bot_interp = (1 - u) * discreteSample(bottom_left.x , bottom_left.y)  + u * discreteSample(bottom_right.x , bottom_right.y) ;  
    return (1 - v) * top_interp + v * bot_interp ; 
}


/**
 * @brief Sample the textures using Integer coordinates
 * 
 * @param x Horizontal coordinates
 * @param y Vertical coordinates
 * @return const T RGB value of the sampled texel
 */
inline const glm::dvec3 discreteSample(int x , int y) const{
    const glm::dvec2 normalized = wrapAroundPixelCoords(static_cast<int>(x) , static_cast<int>(y));
    const glm::dvec3 texel_value = data[normalized.x * height + normalized.y] ;
    return texel_value ; 
}


/**
 * @brief This method samples a value from the equirectangular envmap 
 *! Note : In case the coordinates go beyond the bounds of the texture , we wrap around .
 *! In addition , sampling texels may return a bilinear interpolated value when u,v are converted to a (x ,y) non integer texture coordinate.  
 * @tparam D Type of the coordinates 
 * @param u Horizontal uv coordinates
 * @param v Vertical uv coordinates
 * @return T Returns a texel value of type T 
 */
template<class D> 
inline const glm::dvec3 uvSample(const D u , const D v) const {
    const glm::dvec2 wrap_uv = wrapAroundTexCoords(u , v); 
    const glm::dvec2 pixel_coords = getPixelCoordsFromUv(wrap_uv.x , wrap_uv.y);
    const glm::dvec2 top_left(std::floor(pixel_coords.x) , std::floor(pixel_coords.y));
    const glm::dvec2 top_right(std::floor(pixel_coords.x) + 1 , std::floor(pixel_coords.y));
    const glm::dvec2 bottom_left(std::floor(pixel_coords.x)  , std::floor(pixel_coords.y) + 1);
    const glm::dvec2 bottom_right(std::floor(pixel_coords.x) + 1 , std::floor(pixel_coords.y) + 1);
    const glm::dvec3 texel_value = bilinearInterpolate(top_left , top_right , bottom_left , bottom_right , pixel_coords); 
    return texel_value ; 
} 

/**
 * @brief Bake an equirect envmap to an irradiance map
 * @param delta Size of the step
 * @return std::unique_ptr<TextureData> Texture data containing width , height , and double f_data about the newly created map.
 */
std::unique_ptr<TextureData> computeDiffuseIrradiance(const T delta) const {
    TextureData envmap_tex_data ; 
    envmap_tex_data.data_format = Texture::RGB ; 
    envmap_tex_data.internal_format = Texture::RGB32F ; 
    envmap_tex_data.data_type = Texture::FLOAT;
    envmap_tex_data.width = width ;
    envmap_tex_data.height = height ;  
    envmap_tex_data.mipmaps = 0;
    envmap_tex_data.f_data = new float[width * height * channels];
    unsigned index = 0 ;  
    for(unsigned i = 0 ; i < width ; i++){
            for(unsigned j = 0 ; j < height ; j++){
                    glm::dvec2 uv = getUvFromPixelCoords(i , j);
                    const glm::dvec2 sph = gpgpu_math::uvToSpherical(uv.x , uv.y);
                    const glm::dvec2 sph_to_uv = gpgpu_math::sphericalToUv(sph); 
                    const glm::dvec3 cart = gpgpu_math::sphericalToCartesian(sph.x , sph.y);
                    glm::dvec2 cart_to_sph = gpgpu_math::cartesianToSpherical(cart); 
                    glm::dvec2 uvt = gpgpu_math::sphericalToUv(cart_to_sph); //The problem is here , when the UVs have been obtained from Cartesians -> spherical coordinates. 
                    const glm::dvec3 irrad = uvSample(uvt.x , uvt.y);
                    float x = static_cast<float>(irrad.x) ;
                    float y = static_cast<float>(irrad.y) ;
                    float z = static_cast<float>(irrad.z) ;
                    envmap_tex_data.f_data[index++] = x ;  
                    envmap_tex_data.f_data[index++] = y ; 
                    envmap_tex_data.f_data[index++] = z ; 
            }
    }

    return std::make_unique<TextureData>(envmap_tex_data);
} 


protected:
    std::vector<glm::vec3> data ;
    unsigned width ; 
    unsigned height ;
    unsigned channels ; 
};
```

In addition , here's the code doing the conversions :

```
#ifndef CUBEMAPPROCESSING_CUH
#define CUBEMAPPROCESSING_CUH
#include "Includes.cuh"
#include <cmath>
namespace gpgpu_math{


template<class T>
__host__ __device__
inline const glm::dvec2 uvToSpherical(const T u , const T v){
     const T phi = 2 * PI * u; 
     const T theta = PI * v ;
     return glm::dvec2(phi , theta); 
}

__host__ __device__
inline const glm::dvec2 uvToSpherical(glm::dvec2 uv){
    return uvToSpherical(uv.x , uv.y); 
}

template<class T>
__host__ __device__
inline const glm::dvec2 sphericalToUv(const T phi , const T theta){
    const T u = phi / (2 * PI) ; 
    const T v = theta / PI ; 
    return glm::dvec2(u , v); 
}

__host__ __device__
inline const glm::dvec2 sphericalToUv(glm::dvec2 sph){
    return sphericalToUv(sph.x , sph.y);
}

template<class T>
__host__ __device__
inline const glm::dvec3 sphericalToCartesian(const T phi , const T theta){
    const T z = cos(theta);
    const T x = sin(theta) * cos(phi); 
    const T y = sin(theta) * sin(phi); 
    return glm::normalize(glm::dvec3(x , y , z)); 
}

__host__ __device__
inline const glm::dvec3 sphericalToCartesian(glm::dvec2 sph){
    return sphericalToCartesian(sph.x , sph.y); 
}

template<class T>
__host__ __device__
inline const glm::dvec2 cartesianToSpherical(const T x , const T y , const T z){
    const T theta = acos(z); 
    const T phi = atan2f(y , x);
    return glm::dvec2(phi , theta); 
}

__host__ __device__
inline const glm::dvec2 cartesianToSpherical(glm::dvec3 xyz){
    return cartesianToSpherical(xyz.x , xyz.y , xyz.z); 
}
```

So , the recap of the problem :

1. Converting UV->spherical->UV works.
2. Converting UV->spherical->cartesian->spherical->UV gives roughly good coordinates , but the imprecision seems to create the artifact line in the middle of the screen ... well , I guess it's a precision problem , but maybe I screwed the maths somewhere.
3. The line is exactly in the middle of the X axis , and at x = 0 .
   So , 0 and PI .
4. The artifact seems to be affected by the surrounding pixels , but not by the interpolation , because it has a tendancy to keep the same RGB value .

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem at the level of coordinate vectors, without going via an image? Can you give a coordinate vector which gains huge errors from the round trip? When you do, can you tell which step is failing? Note that for θ=0 you get x=y=0 so the reverse operation won't be able to recover φ. Not sure that's your problem, since I assumed θ to be vertical.

Comment: @MvG : The values don't seem to diverge weirdly . Concerning atan2 , If I understood it well , it is supposed to handle the y = x = 0 case by returning 0 , and the seam is present even in regular cases.

Comment: Assuming values never diverge much, the conclusion would be to find fault with your code turning positions into pixel colors. I consider that unlikely, tough. But you can check that easily: for an output position on the seam, is the input position reasonable (and the color value perhaps wrong?) or is the input position for that from a bad position? You might want to read and follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to provide a reproducing example others can use to investigate your problem.

Comment: `data[normalized.x * height + normalized.y]` suggests you are accessing the image data in [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) which is contrary to the typical conventions I'm familiar with. Be careful to check whether this might lead to *x* and *y* values being swapped, i.e. *x* going down and *y* to the right. Such a swap might make θ increase to the right, so your seams might be θ∈{0,π} after all. `atan2` always returning 0 means all output pixels take their color from a single vertical position for these, thus the seam of constant color.

Comment: @MvG it was indeed a case of swapped coordinates that I found somewhere else in the code . 
My bad , thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my apparently useful comments into a coherent answer.*

In `sphericalToCartesian` you have

```
    const T z = cos(theta);
    const T x = sin(theta) * cos(phi); 
    const T y = sin(theta) * sin(phi);
```

and `cartesianToSpherical` tries to invert that using

```
    const T theta = acos(z); 
    const T phi = atan2f(y , x);
```

but if θ is a multiple of π then `sin(theta)` is zero so `x = y = 0`. This results in `phi = atan2f(0, 0) = 0` and not the original value for φ. So for some values of θ the coordinates don't survive the round trip from spherical to Cartesian and back.

Typically you would expect that situation to occur at the north and south pole of your sphere, which should correspond to the top and bottom rim of the texture image. But it seems you also have swapped your `x` and `y` coordinates. When you write `data[normalized.x * height + normalized.y]` that is accessing the pixels in [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) where the more common convention for image data is row-major, i.e. would use `data[normalized.x + normalized.y * width]`. This can cause the critical values for θ to correspond to surprising locations within your image, leading to these vertical seams instead of horizontal peculiarities at the very top and bottom.